# After upgrade GitLab, has problems with custom port on which it is running.

Tags: gitlab

After GitLab has auto-upgraded itself to GitLab Community Edition 8.10.0, it stopped redirecting some internal urls (like Sign Out or Create Milestone) to the custom port of 9000. Although we still have it specified in `gitlab.rb` like this:

```
external_url 'http://domain.com:9000'
```

Anyone any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a bug that was introduced in version 8.10.0. You can see the full issue [here](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/20131) but the solution is to upgrade to version 8.10.1

If you can't upgrade then the workaround is to add this line to your `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb` file:

```rb
nginx['proxy_set_headers'] = { "Host" => "<YOUR HOST>:<YOUR PORT>" }
```

And then reconfigure GitLab by running:

```sh
sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure
```

Comment: Meanwhile it auto upgraded to 8.10.1 and got fixed by itself :) Thanks for the tip anyway.